# EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a number of application roles, and automatically the SQL Server database created the following:

```
declare @idx as int
declare @randomPwd as nvarchar(64)
declare @rnd as float
select @idx = 0
select @randomPwd = N''
select @rnd = rand((@@CPU_BUSY % 100) + ((@@IDLE % 100) * 100) + 
       (DATEPART(ss, GETDATE()) * 10000) + ((cast(DATEPART(ms, GETDATE()) as int) % 100) * 1000000))
while @idx < 64
begin
   select @randomPwd = @randomPwd + char((cast((@rnd * 83) as int) + 43))
   select @idx = @idx + 1
select @rnd = rand()
end
declare @statement nvarchar(4000)
select @statement = N'CREATE APPLICATION ROLE [AppRole_01] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [AppRole_01], ' + N'PASSWORD = N' + QUOTENAME(@randomPwd,'''')
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement

GO
```

Now here I see `EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement` and I can't understand

1. Why is calling this procedure?
2. I've searched the database server and I didn't find any procedure `sp_executesql` especially `dbo.sp_executesql`

Is there someone to guide me thru this issue?

Comment: Its a System Extended Procedure in `[master]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a system SP. It comes shipped with SQL Server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933299(v=sql.80).aspx

The query you posted is creating a dynamic SQL and executing it.

**Edit**
Any visual tool you use to manage your DB is, behind the curtains, creating that kind of command and sending it to the engine (and is it doing all the job all the time). You can see it by running a profiler.

You cannot find that system SP and it's good because that way it's not easy to hack in the RDBMS and do nasty things. Please don't even try to change things by updating/altering system objects.

Comment: First I can't find this procedure anywhere in my SQL Server... And second, the only thing I did was to create an Application Role... so What this procedure produce? related with my Application Role... I use the SQLServer 2008R2

Comment: The procedure executes the query stored in the variable `@statement`

Comment: It's creating a string with the `CREATE APPLICATION ROLE..` sql statement in it and then using `sp_ExecuteSQL` to execute that string as a SQL command.  It's not executing the command directly because of the preceeding SQL commands that it is using to generate a random password for the AppRole (which is really a type of Login/User).

Comment: @jean Thank you very much for your efforts.. I was never intent to scratch this 'sp' or any other 'sp' I was just curious where it was... thank you very much...